# How to implement SEO friendly Spotify/Rhapsody/iTunes-like Interface with or without Iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, seo

I have a site that is similar in layout and function to the app of any streaming music service (Spotify/Rhapsody/iTunes/).  I've got a persistent play control at the bottom, persistent navigation on the left, and the center/bulk of the page is used to pick what you want to play, read more about what you are going to play, etc.

I've implemented it in the most logical (for a programmer) way using an iframe for the center content.  But is there a better way, a way more conformant with SEO?

I suspect the current approach is terrible for SEO (even with sitemaps) and might violate some cardinal rule because I would need to add some code on each page to check if it is being viewed through the proper iframed interface and if it is not then the page would need to redirect to load up the full interface with the desired content in the center iframe of that interface (that's how I would and have solved similar problems ten years ago).

Rather than redirect on landing I could simply add the interface elements but unless some unknown magic happens when they explore content the page will reload and anything they were playing would stop playing as the page unloads.  I do not want to interrupt play, even to resume it at the right spot.

Is the old and reliable reloading mechanism the only real solution?  Can you get do it and not be SEO penalized?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your case the UX is the most important thing to consider and to work on it, then the other things come like SEO.

You have to focus only on the most important pages like singers pages, geners and playlists, other pages no need to index them, you can avoid indexing them by adding canonical links or from robots.txt or by adding meta tags noindex.

Other thing is the URLs and advanced techniques, when the user click on link you should get the results without refreshing the page using JS, but here Google will not be able to crawl these pages.

Here you need to use advanced techniques like "Progressive Web Enhancements) and the best example to see is Tumblr.

All the pages are done by using this technique which allow them to add a great user experience and at the same time Google can index all the pages.

Example for the links:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/singer-page" onclick="getSingerPageJS();">Singer Page</a>
```

You have to read more about it, also the old technique "graceful degration" for old browsers can help you a lot.

Comment: Good input, thanks.  On the UX side I think the UX is just as I want it, mirroring popular streaming media service apps.  The interface seems most efficient to me, and the widespread model for finding/playing media suggests it is good or, at the very least, well know and comfortable to people.  I'll take your advice and add the links in the "Progressive Web Enhancement" style, right now they are just JS actions.  But, I'm still not sure about the larger question of whether I "restore" the app interface on a content page via redirection or some other method, and how that impacts SEO.